# Running Total with Adjustment Count

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sum, common-table-expression

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 and trying to compute a running total WITH a periodic quantity adjustment.

My data looks like this:

[image: Before Data]
I want to keep the running quantity accurate, which in and of itself isn't hard. I have that in `RunningQuantity` column.

However in order to do this currently, I need to have the entire history of transactions.

Which means subtracting out the inventory shrink when a cycle count occurs.

I also have a column that is the `CycleCount` quantity. I'm hoping I can use the cycle count date as a starting/reset date within the running totals to compute from that date?

My calculation would be:

```
 -If PIQtyAdjustment <> 0 then RunningQuantity = PIQtyAdjustment + NetQuantityChange
 -If PIQtyAdjustment = 0 then Previous Day RunningQuantity + CurrentDay NetQuantityChange
```

How do I do this?

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks, 
justin

Comment: Perhaps I will create a really great query for you, then take a screenshot of it, and paste in that image. **hint** provide sample data as a formatted text table.

Comment: This is why America cant have nice things. I figured it out. I'll post a screenshot of my happy face.